# New line required while sending an email from asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have the below lines of code to send an email from my aspx page.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //SmtpClient mail = new SmtpClient();
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mm.From = new MailAddress(txt_email.Text);
        mm.To.Add("excelguesthouse@gmail.com");
        //MailMessage mm=new MailMessage();
        mm.Body = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", txt_fname.Text, txt_lname.Text, txt_email.Text, txt_phone.Text, txt_details.Text);
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Subject = cmb_type.Text;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("excelguesthouse", "excelhome");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        object userstate = mm;
        client.Send(mm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I am receiving the email fine.

But I want the email in a proper format with line breaks. So Can anyone tell me how to add line breaks in the above code to display email, phone and details values in 2nd and third lines.

Comment: If you claim that the body is HTML, you need to send valid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

you have already set

```
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

just use `<br />` in the part where you want line breaks

Comment: Good spot, I hadn't seen it was html!

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want have break lines in your mm.Body.
Change this

```
mm.Body = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", txt_fname.Text, txt_lname.Text, txt_email.Text, txt_phone.Text, txt_details.Text);
```

to this:

```
mm.Body = string.Format("{0},{1}<br />{2}<br />{3}<br />{4}", txt_fname.Text, txt_lname.Text, txt_email.Text, txt_phone.Text, txt_details.Text);
```

That will give you break lines between your First/Last name and email, email and phone, phone and details

Answer (score 1):

Edited after Rex's answer pointed out it's HTML. Newline won't work as it's HTML. You need to use the `<br />` tag.

Saved for future use:

In a plain text email you can use the @ in `@"Some text"` however this doesn't work well with string.Format. Instead I do this:

```
string.Format("This is one line{0}This is another {1}", Environment.NewLine, "SomeText");
```

Which adds a NewLine character into the string. Remember you only needs one!

```
string.Format("This is one line{0}This is another {1}{0}And another line{0}{0}And some more", Environment.NewLine, "SomeText");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying that the message's body "IsHtml", so use HTML!

```
mm.Body = string.Format("{0} {1} <br /> {2} <br /> {3} <br /> {4}", txt_fname.Text, txt_lname.Text, txt_email.Text, txt_phone.Text, txt_details.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for quick reply and providing the exact code :D

Answer (score -1):

Just try putting `\n\n` where ever you want a break. It worked for me ...

Example:

```
mail.Body = "\n\nHi,\n\n "  + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] + " \n\nsent you a message: " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4] + " \n\nYou can contact me via email:  " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2] + " or\n\nphone:  " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3] + " " ;
```